# Finding maximum value in Python vs. C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, execution-time

I am just curious as to why finding the maximum value in C++ is faster than in Python3. Here is a snippet of my code in both languages:

C++:

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = {45, 67, 89};
    int temp = 0;

    for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
        if(arr[n] > temp) 
            temp = arr[n];
    }

    cout << "Biggest number: " << temp << endl;
}
```

Python:

```
def Main():
    numbers = ['87', '67', '32', '43']
    print(max(numbers))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

As it is illustrated in the code, I am finding the maximum value in C++ via looping each element in an array as compared to using the max() method in Python.

I then ran the code on the terminal to find their execution times and found out that it takes approximately 0.006s(C++) and 0.032s(Python). Is there a way to further shorten Python's execution time?

Comment: "*finding the maximum value in C++ is slower than in Python3*" ... That's the *opposite* of what your data says.

Comment: You might as well be using `std::max_element` to match the Python one-liner that doesn't involve reinvented code.

Comment: Did you test this with code that is compiled with optimizations turned on?  If not, this is meaningless.  Please post the command-line you used to compile your example.  If it's Visual Studio, please create a "Release" build, not a "Debug" build.

Answer (score 0):

Python is an interpreted language. Python has to read the text file with the python code, parse it, and only then begin executing it.

By the time the C++ code executes, the C++ compiler already did all the heavy lifting of compiling C++ into native machine language code that gets directly executed by the CPU.

It is possible to precompile Python code; this'll save some overhead, but the C++ code will still get the benefit of C++ compile-time optimization. With a small array size, an aggressive C++ compiler is likely to unroll the loop, and maybe even compute the maximum value at compile time, instead of at runtime; so all you end up executing is:

```
cout << "Biggest number: " << 89 << endl;
```

This is something that, theoretically, Python can also do; however that'll take even more CPU cycles to figure out, at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using a larger vector than the toy example above, I would give numpy a shot.

```
# set up a vector with 50000 random elements
a = np.random.randint(0,100000,50000)

max_val = np.max(a)
```

Very fast relative to looping.

My computer shows it about 12x faster to use np.max than the built in max() operation in python. C++ would be even faster as it's a compiled language. (Numpy wraps around low level packages that are optimized C code.)